# If statement not evaluated correctly

Tags: bash, function, if-statement

I have a simple bash function that returns 3 numerical values: 0, 1, 2
When testing for the return value I get the correct value depending on the one returned from the function. # echo $?  -> 0, 1, 2

However, when using an if-else statement the return value is not evaluate as I expected. For example when the function returns value = 2 in the if-else statement the elif [ $? -eq 1 ]; then is choosen

```
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "0"
elif [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
    echo "1"
elif [ "$?" -eq "2" ]; then
    echo "2"
else
    echo "Incorrect"
fi
```

Result:
output is: 1
I expect:
output is: 2

Any thoughts.
Cheers,
Roland

Comment: Run the script with the `-x` option to investigate more about what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

By running `[ "$?" -eq "0" ]` you are changing the value of `$?`. If you want to compare it several times, store its value into a non-magical variable and compare it instead.

Other option is to use `case`:

```
case $? in
    (0) echo 0 ;;
    (1) echo 1 ;;
    (2) echo 2 ;;
    (*) echo Incorrect
esac
```

Comment: Thank you @choroba, that makes sense. And it worked. I get the correct behavior.